# Responsive menu show and hide on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to write a responsive menu. It's actually works but I can't get the on clik effect in CSS. For this moment I'm using a hover. How to make that when the screen width is lower than 750px I have to click on menu from pic. number 2 (ul) to show menu from pic. number 3 (li) ? This is a one page site so when I clik on some element from drop down menu it's should hide menu agin (li).

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="li"><a href="#">WITAJ</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a href="#">O MNIE</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a href="#">DOŚWIADCZENIE</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a href="#">CO ROBIĘ?</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MOJE PRACE</a></li
        ></ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {      
    header nav#menu ul:hover > li{
        display:block !important;
    }

    header nav#menu ul li{
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot achieve a click effect in CSS. It is common to use JavaScript for that.
This is an easy jQuery solution:

```
$(function() {
  var menuVisible = false;
  $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
    if (menuVisible) {
      $('#myMenu').css({'display':'none'});
      menuVisible = false;
      return;
    }
    $('#myMenu').css({'display':'block'});
    menuVisible = true;
  });
  $('#myMenu').click(function() {
    $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    menuVisible = false;
  });
});
```

It also hides the menu, after the user clicked on an entry.

In CSS, you have to force the menu to be visible or not by using media queries. Here an example: [sfplex](http://www.sfplex.li/team/)

This is the HTML structure of this example:

```
<div id="menuBtn">click me</div>
<nav id="myMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>entry 1</li>
    <li>entry 2</li>
    <li>entry 3</li>
    <li>entry 4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

See the working example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g825b/).

Comment: Don't forget you will need to only make the dropdown menu appear ("onClick") when the menu button is "visible" - otherwise it will show every time the user clicks on the menu when it's full width... I think you will need to do a preliminary check in your function to check whether the "minimal" menu button is visible, and then run the "if(menuVisible)" function

Comment: No, you don't need such a check in JS. You achieve this in CSS Media Queries. If the button was clicked, it has to be visible.

Comment: Good point. Very good point. It's not 10am yet... I'm not fully awake :P

Comment: Well, so I have to create a menu button because for now (in responsive mode) It's just ul with background image and position left :)

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: Not exactly. Could you give me menu structure in HTML for your script ? I have couple problems.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$('#menu').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu ul').css("display", "block");
});
$('#menu a').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu ul').css("display", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using JavaScript for this purpose like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#floor").click(function(){
 $("#floor_panel").slideToggle("slow");
  })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="floor">FLOOR ▾ </div>
  <div id="floor_panel">
   <form name="floor" action="{{ url_for('select_work', url='Floor') }}" method="post">
    {{ floor.name }}
    <div id="choose"><input type="submit" value="Choose"></div>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

It displays panel **floor** and by pressing it - panel **floor_panel** will slide.