# How to display content selectively in an ajax menu

Tags: ajax, menu

I have a menu in a PHP page:

```
<li data-target='MA'><a href="Disciplines.php#MA"><span>M.A.</span></a></li>
<li data-target='MBA'><a href="Disciplines.php#MCom"><span>M.Com.</span></a></li>
<li data-target='MBA'><a href="Disciplines.php#BE"><span>B.E.</span></a></li>
```

and I have content:

```
<p id="MA"   class='content'>MA</p>
<p id="MCOM" class='content'>MCOM</p>
<p id="BE"   class='content'>BE</p>
```

I have to selectively show the content. How do I do it?

Comment: I have to actually fetch content for MA, MCOM, BE from MySQL DB and display

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for javascript solution.

For example look on the answer to this question:
[Responsive menu show and hide on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259016/responsive-menu-show-and-hide-on-click)

Solution:

```js
function switchContent(id) {
  var content = $(('#' + id));
  $('.content').not(content).hide();
  content.show();
}

function handleHash() {
  switchContent(location.hash.substring(1));
}

window.onhashchange = handleHash;
$(handleHash);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li data-target='MA'><a class='link' href="#MA"><span>M.A.</span></a></li>
<li data-target='MCOM'><a class='link' href="#MCOM"><span>M.Com.</span></a></li>
<li data-target='BE'><a class='link' href="#BE"><span>B.E.</span></a></li>

<p id="MA"   class='content'>MA</p>
<p id="MCOM" class='content'>MCOM</p>
<p id="BE"   class='content'>BE</p>
```

Comment: I have to actually fetch content for MA, MCOM, BE from MySQL DB and display.

Comment: Is content big? In the case if it is just few paragraphs - you need to extract it on the page load and put in the content paragraphs. Then you will just hide\show them by JS. In the case content is big or it's depends from the user entered values you will need to create ajax solution - one more PHP page for select data and JS that ask that page for the data