# Responsive menu disappears when screen resized a few times

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

My responsive menu disappears when screen returns to maximum width. I was using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259016/responsive-menu-show-and-hide-on-click) but I modified it a bit

```
    $(function() {
  if ( $(window).width() < 700) {
  var menuVisible = false;
    $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
      if (menuVisible) {
        $('#menu').css({'display':'none'});
        menuVisible = false;
        return;
      }
      $('#menu').css({'display':'block'});
      menuVisible = true;
    });

    $('#menu').click(function() {
      $(this).css({'display':'none'});
      menuVisible = false;
    });
  }else{
    menuVisible = true;
  };
});
```

Comment: You should use CSS media queries for the automatique width visibility. Use JS only for the click event

Comment: if that's function's not there the dropdown menu is shown on default when browsing a page. it hides like half the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `windows resize event` to call you function again on resizing the window

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ( $(window).width() > 700) {
      $('#menu').css({'display':'block'});
    }
})
```

I made those edits to your code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jfhLmgvc/2/

---

This code also can be more simplify, with a little css like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/jmbup8g3/

The script:

```
$(function() {
  $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 700){
      $('#menu').fadeToggle(300);
    }
  });
  $('#menu').click(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 700){
      $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    }
  });
});
```

the css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) { 
  #menu{display:block !important;}
}
```